# Заменить подстроку в строке не используя replace

Tags: c++, строки, stl

Разбираюсь с c++. Пытаюсь заменить подстроку длины 2, на строку неизвестной длины, длина минимум 1.

Знаю, что вначале (find) ищется позиция, в которую нужно вставить строку, затем (replace). Также можно сделать поиск, удаление, затем insert.
Какие еще есть способы? Какой самый лучший по производительности?

Comment: Очень неконкретное задание. Определите точнее, а то очень неоднозначно...

Comment: @Harry я хочу заменить подстроку в строке без replace, как можно более производительней

Comment: Это - не ответ. Даже то, меняете ли вы N символов на N символов, или N на M - играет огромную роль. Как эти символы определяются etc etc. Ваш вопрос - типа "хочу написать программу" Какую? "Красивую!"...

Comment: @Harry хочу чтобы было похоже на функцию printf. Чтобы вместо символа %d было число к примеру, но не знаю с чего начать

Comment: Это слишком большая задача, особенно с учетом всяких форматирований...

Comment: @Harry если только с %d или %s, я хочу понять идею, как происходит

Comment: Сканируете с начала посимвольно и переносите куда-то в другую строку. Встретив %, разбираетесь, что там дальше, пишете в ту новую строку вместо %d/%s/... нужные данные, продолжаете сканирование. Если строка - не много мегабайт с единственным %d в конце - времени это займет немного...

Answer (score 1):

Для тех, кому, возможно, по религиозным соображениям, не подходит "заковыристый алгоритм" поиска подстроки с последующей заменой, могу предложить ещё один вариант решения той же задачи, наиболее близкий к поведению printf:

```
#define _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE // Чтобы MS Visual Studio заткнулась и не 
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS   // цеплялась к использованию itoa.
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE  // (При желании, можно вместо itoa использовать std::to_chars или std::to_string в С++17)
// <stdarg.h> используется для работы с т.н. элипсисом - переменным списком аргументов,
// обозначаемым троеточием в сигнатуре функции/метода. 
// Из него нам потребуются 4 макроса:
// va_list   - структура, с которой ассоциированы аргументы из элипсиса
// va_start  - начало извлечения аргументов из va_list
// va_arg    - взять очередной аргумент из va_list
// va_end    - завершить работу с va_list
#include <stdarg.h> 
#include <string.h> //для memmove
#include <stdio.h>  //для оригинального printf
#include <cstdlib>  //для itoa
#define min(a,b) ((a<=b)?a:b) // Почему-то min отсутствует в stdlib.h/cstdlib, раньше он там точно был

// result_buffer - место под строку, которую хотим получить в итоге
// buffer_size - размер буфера - количество символов в result_buffer 
// format - формат, a'la printf (поддерживает только placeholder-ы - места подстановки - %s и %d)
// ... - любые аргументы в любом количестве (должны быть строго int и char* и соответствовать формату: %d и %s соответственно).
void my_sprintf(char* result_buffer, size_t buffer_size, const char* format, ...) {
    if ((buffer_size < 1) || (!result_buffer))return; // защита от дурака № 1

    result_buffer[buffer_size - 1] = '\0'; // защита от дурака № 2

    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, format);
    char* pbuffer = result_buffer;//pbuffer будет обозначать текущее место в итоговой строке (буфере)

    while (*format) // Пока не достигли конца строки - '\0'
        if (*format == '%') // Если placeholder (место подстановки в строку)
            if (format[1]) { // Если есть тип данных подставляемых в строку
                switch (format[1]) { // В зависимости от типа данных подставляемых в строку
                case 's': { // Если в строку подставляем другую строку в стиле Си
                    ++format;//Пропускаем %
                    char* str = va_arg(ap, char*);//взять очередной аргумент-строку
                    const size_t len = ::strlen(str);//узнать её длину    
                    const size_t remain_len = buffer_size - (pbuffer - result_buffer);//вычислить оставшееся место в буфере
                    const size_t byte_count_to_move = min(len, remain_len);//сколько байт копируем - меньшее между оставшимся местом в буфере и длиной строки
                    ::memmove(pbuffer, str, byte_count_to_move);//копируем строку в буфер
                    pbuffer += byte_count_to_move;//перемещаем позицию буфера
                    ++format;//Пропускаем 's'
                } break;
                case 'd': { // Если в строку подставляем число в 10чной системе счисления
                    ++format;//Пропускаем %
                    int val = va_arg(ap, int);//взять очередной аргумент-целое
                    char* intstring = itoa(val, pbuffer, 10);//преобразовать в строку
                    while (*(intstring++) != '\0');//найти нулевой символ
                    pbuffer = --intstring;//изменить позицию буфера
                    ++format;//Пропускаем 'd'
                } break;
                default: ++format;//Если какой-то неизвестный тип - пропускаем
                }
            } else break;//Если типа подставляемых данных нет == строка кончилсь
        else {//Если не placeholder (место подстановки) - копируем подстроку из строки формата
            const char* format_string_begin = format;//ищем конец строки или начало placeholder-а (места подстановки в строке формата)
            for (; !((*format == '\0') || (*format == '%')); ++format);
            const size_t format_string_len = format - format_string_begin;//вычисляем размер подстроки, перемещаемой в буфер из строки формата
            const size_t remain_len = buffer_size - (pbuffer - result_buffer);//вычисляем оставшееся место в буфере
            const size_t byte_count_to_move = min(format_string_len, remain_len);//вычисляем сколько можно переместить в буфер - наименьшее между длиной строки формата и свободным местом в буфере
            ::memmove(pbuffer, format_string_begin, byte_count_to_move);//перемещаем
            pbuffer += byte_count_to_move;//смещаем текущую позицию в буфере
            
        }
    *pbuffer = '\0';//Добавить в конец строки терминирующий ноль.
    va_end(ap);
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    char buffer[1000];

    my_sprintf(buffer, 1000, "Hello %s*%d + %d // %s %d %s", "world", 123, 100500, "Cool stuff", 13, "Ahha");
    printf("%s\n", buffer); // выведет: Hello world * 123 + 100500 // Cool stuff 13 Ahha
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: у меня выдает много ощибок в visual studio и в онлайн компиляторах  Ошибка C2446 !=: нет преобразования "int" в "char *"

Comment: @kaliarty код изначально писал вслепую, по памяти, поэтому кое-какие ошибки были: не хватало нескольких заголовков (в принципе, кто знаком с itoa, memmove, min и т.д., мог бы легко понять, что не компилировалось из-за них), плюс MSVS не одобряет itoa (как это поправить см. комментарий в коде). Сейчас код поправил, теперь он должен запуститься у любого. На MSVC 2019 - сработает точно.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще-то один из наиболее эффективных (в т.ч. по производительности) алгоритмов поиска подстроки в строке - алгоритм Бойера-Мура (он же - "алгоритм Бойера-Мура-Хорспула"; его можно загуглить, если лень - вот [статья на английском](https://cppsecrets.com/users/100741121141051219710912197115104485164103109971051084699111109/Boyer-Moore-Algorithm-for-Pattern-Searching.php)). Уж точно он **гораздо эффективнее посимвольного поиска**.

Допустим, Вы реализуете этот алгоритм (или будете использовать искать подстроку с помощью C++17 - используя [std::search + std::boyer_moore_searcher](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/search)). Тогда, на выходе у Вас могут быть индексы/указатели/итераторы - в зависимости от используемого алгоритма - так или иначе определяющие границы найденной подстроки. Далее, я буду, для краткости, использовать обобщённый термин "итератор", но не в буквальном смысле итераторов C++, а в широком смысле такой абстракции как "итератор", каковой являются не только итераторы C++, но также и указатели или индексы.

Итак, так или иначе, в результате любого поиска подстроки в строке (при её наличии), Вы имеете итераторы, определяющие границы этой подстроки.

Будем считать, что для любой строки, в т.ч. найденной в результате поиска подстроки, определены следующие итераторы: Begin - начало строки, Size - количество символов в строке, End - конец строки - символ, следующий за последним, такие, что для них верны все следующие уравнения:

```
End - Begin = Size;
Begin + Size = End;
End - Size = Begin;
```

Будем также считать, что String - вся строка целиком, в которой осуществляется поиск, а Substring - подстрока, найденная в строке String.

Тогда, получим следующее (псевдокод на C++):

```
// Шаг 1 - найти подстроку:
string_view Substring("substring");
auto Begin = find_substring(String, Substring);//алгоритм find_substring - на Ваше усмотрение любой, позволяющий найти подстроку, например - предложенный мной выше Бойер-Мур

// Шаг 2 - заменить подстроку на что-то другое
string NewString; // Новая строка

// Ключевое действие: выделяем место под количество символов,
// достаточное для хранения новой строки. Нам нужно:
// Вычесть из размера исходной строки размер заменяемой подстроки и 
// прибавить размер той строки, которой хотим заменить заменяемую:
NewString.resize(String.size() - Substring.size() + ReplacementString.size());

// Далее воспользуемся читерством в стиле C - функцией побайтового копирования:
// Шаг 1: перемещаем левую часть исходной строки, до заменяемой подстроки, в новую строку:
memmove(NewString.data(), String.data(), sizeof(string::char_type) * (Begin - String.begin())); // sizeof(string::char_type) - размер символа (1 байт, если char_type это char); (Begin - String.begin()) - длина левой части исходной строки, до найденной подстроки

// Шаг 2: перемещаем середину - замещающую подстроку:
memmove(NewString.data() + (Begin - String.begin()), ReplacementString.data(), sizeof(string::char_type) * ReplacementString.size());

// Шаг 3: перемещаем правую часть исходной строки, следующую после заменяемой подстроки:
memmove(NewString.data() + (Begin - String.begin()) + ReplacementString.size(), 
Begin + Substring.size(),
sizeof(string::char_type) * (String.end() - (Begin + Substring.size())));
//(String.end() - (Begin + Substring.size())) - оставшееся количество символов, которые нужно переместить:
//Символ, следующий за последним в исходной строке, за вычетом символа,
//следующего за последним в найденной подстроке (его положение в исходной строке)

// Итог: заменена подстрока в строке: строка NewString содержит строку, 
// полученную путём замены подстроки Substring строкой ReplacementString в строке String.
// Дальше можно вызвать clear и shrink_to_fit на всех строках, кроме NewString - она и есть результат замены.
```

Обращаю внимание: если ReplacementString.size() > Substring.size(), то выделять дополнительную память/создавать отдельную строку NewString придётся 100%. Если же ReplacementString.size() <= Substring.size(), то можно обойтись и строкой String, не создавать NewString. При этом, принцип останется тем же, только можно будет пропустить 1й шаг (перемещение в памяти): 1я часть строки String, которая до Substring, уже на месте, останется лишь передвинуть ReplacementString на позицию Begin, а потом, на позицию Begin + ReplacementString.string() сдвинуть ту часть исходной строки String, которая была после Begin + Substring.size() до String.end().

Если всё равно не понятно, то рекомендую попробовать всё это проделать с парой небольших строк на листочке в клеточку вручную (серьёзно, это часто помогает разобраться в алгоритме).

Comment: Да не работает `..printf` таким образом... Просто сканирует.

Comment: @Harry, мы про printf или про scanf? - printf ничего не сканирует: она берёт строку формата и переменный список параметров. Если Вам было нужно буквальное поведение с переменными аргументами, то об этом следовало сказать прямо. Может Вас интересует <stdarg.h> - https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdarg.h ?

Comment: Именно printf. Сканирует форматную строку, а не начинает камими-то заковыристыми или не очень алгоритмами искать в ней проценты...

Comment: Может вроде такого (см. пример) - https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdarg.h ?

Comment: Ну, не хотите понимать - не надо :)